# How send a request to a service in XML-WSDL in nodejs

Tags: node.js, xml, soap, axios, wsdl

I have an XML in Web Services(WSDL). This file contain many service that I want to send a request to one of this service in Nodejs. But I do not know anything about XML and WSDL. I just want to request to a service and send some parameters to this and get a response.

This xml service contains some service like this:

```
<wsdl:operation name="bpPaymentRequest">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="bpPayRequest">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="bpPayRequestResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

and i want to request to this service something like this:

```
const response = await axios.post( "https://example.com/services/pgw?bpPaymentRequest" , payReqParams)
```

But if I test this, I know this is wrong! How should I send a request to this service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are willing to call a `SOAP` web service from `axios`.

SOAP web services talk `XML`. That means they accept XML as input and return another XML as response. In contrast with `Json APIs`, they do not accept JSON data input.

So,

1. You need to prepare an XML for input
2. Send it via `axios`
3. Parse the result assuming that is a valid XML

A sample code would be like this:

```
var xml ='<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"\
                            xmlns:web="http://shaparak/">\
            <soapenv:Header/>\
            <soapenv:Body>\
              <web:param>\
                <web:amount>123</web:amount>\
              </web:param>\
            </soapenv:Body>\
          </soapenv:Envelope>';

axios.post('https://example.com/services/pgw?bpPaymentRequest',
           xml,
           {headers:
             {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}
           }).then(res=>{
             console.log(res);
           }).catch(err=>{console.log(err)});
```

**Attention**

Are you implementing a bank gateway for payments with Mellat or Shaparak? They have some implementation for Node.js.